# Proof that DFT is symmetric

Tags: fourier, proof

I am working through the proof that the DFT is symmetric from Lyons - *Understanding Digital Signal Processing*

I don't quite understand the use of the $N$ variable. My understanding is that in $X(N-m)$, it indicates the number of points of the DFT (e.g. we calculate the DFT for 16 frequencies, a 16-point DFT).
$m$ indicates an arbitary frequency in the range $0 \leq m \leq N$.

In the summation, I understand it means the number of samples in our signal $x(n)$.

So in the second step to third step, $N/N=1$ is only valid when the size of the DFT is equal to the number of samples in the signal. In another example, in which we say take 16-point DFT of a 500-sample signal, this proof would not be valid. I wonder what I am missing.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DFT is defined as

$$X[k] = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x[n]e^{-j2\pi\frac{nk}{N}} $$

Roughly speaking the DFT maps $N$ samples in the time domain to $N$ samples in the frequency domain. To elaborate: it follows directly from the definition that both $x[n]$ and $X[k]$ are periodic with $N$. So both $x[n]$ and $X[k]$ have only $N$ independent values.

> in which we say take 16-point DFT of a 500-sample signal

That is sloppy language. You can ONLY take the 16-point DFT of a 16-point signal. If your signal is longer than it needs to be cut down to size by windowing & truncation.

Comment: *:...it follows directly from the definition that both $x[n]$ and $X[k]$ are periodic with $N$."* -------------  Yay!!!  I'm glad to read someone else say this.

Answer (score 2):

By definition, $N$ is **both** the number of DFT points in the frequency domain and the number of samples in time domain.

If you request a 16-point FFT of a 500-sample signal in MATLAB or Python for instance, you are actually truncating the signal and only using the first 16 samples. Conversely, you  use zero-padding when the required DFT size is larger than the number of time samples.